# How can I go about controlling 1 view controller from another?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, uicontainerview

So I have the following layout for my iOS app.

[image: Storyboard Layout!]

What I'm intending to do is put a table view in the purpleVC to control the Green viewcontroller...the top peachVC will have text in it which will need to change. I'm just not sure how to control one view controller from another. This includes having the purple slide in and out when a button on the GreenVC is clicked. I know there are classes out there to do this however I want to learn as well.

TESTING DELEGATES:

***MAINVIEW CONTROLER***

```
import UIKit

protocol Purpleprotocol {
    func buttonpressed()
}

protocol Greenprotocol {

}

extension UIViewController {

    func alert(message: String, title: String = "") {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController,Purpleprotocol,Greenprotocol {
    weak var infoNav : UINavigationController?
    weak var greenVC: GreenVC?
    weak var purpleVC: PurpleVC?
    weak var peachVC: PeachVC?

    func buttonpressed() {
        alert(message: "This is message")
        print("buttonpressed")
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
        greenVC?.greenlabel.text = String(hour) + ":" + String(minutes)
    }

       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "contentSegue" {
            let infoNav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController

        }
    }
}
```

***PURPLEVIEW CONTROLER***

```
class PurpleVC: UIViewController {

    var delegate: Purpleprotocol?

    @IBAction func butclick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        alert(message: "infunction")
        delegate?.buttonpressed()
           }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Thanks
R

Comment: Not fully sure on if this would work through a navigation controller, I have done something similar but segueing from one View Controller directly to the other. Essentially the thought was creating a delegate, and conforming to the delegate in the second VC. T first VC that fires a method in the second View controller (controlling it in the desired way) and then when I wanted to perform the segue, I would load up the altered second VC and display it. 
Maybe something similar can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the case but to see a few examples:

**A)** You can connect it through the delegates. Your main view controller has 3 child view controllers to which it should report changes. It should also assign itself as a delegate to all 3 child controllers where it will get all notifications for events. This would look like

```
func purpleViewController(sender: PVC, selectedItem: Item) {
    self.greenViewController.showItem(item: selectedItem)
    self.peachVC.showItem(item: selectedItem)
}

func purpleViewController(sender: PVC, shouldSetMenuClosed closed: Bool) {
    self.menuConstraint.constant = closed ? targetWidth : 0.0
}
```

**B)** You may have a data model which controls the whole screen and has a delegate for each of the children. The model will report any changes to its delegates so they may react accordingly. Main view controller would create an instance of this model when it loads and pass it to all of the children view controllers. The children would then directly manipulate the model:

In green controller:

```
func onTap() {
    mode.menuShown = !mode.menuShown
}
```

In model:

```
var menuShown: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        self.menuDelegate.model(self, changedMenuShownStateTo: menuShown)
    }
}
```

In main view controller:

```
func model(_ sender: Model, changedMenuShownStateTo shown:Bool) {
    self.menuConstraint.constant = shown ? 0.0 : targetWidth
}
```

**C)** You can use notifications where any of the controllers may post to notification center a custom notification and other controllers may observe the notifications and act accordingly.

There are many other ways in doing so but these probably most popular. See if any of them fits you...

Answer (score 0):

Delegation.

Your `MainViewController` will become a delegate to each of the embedded VC's that want to pass back information.  From your description you'll need two delegate relationships:

```
protocol PurpleProtocol {
    func selected(row: Int, text: String)
}

protocol GreenProtocol {
    func slideButtonPressed()
}
```

Have MainViewController implement these protocols.  Give identifiers to the *embed segues*.  You can find them in the *Document Outline* view.  In prepareForSegue, retain pointers to the embedded VC's and pass your self as the delegate:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, PurpleProtocol, GreenProtocol {
    weak var greenVC: GreenViewController?
    weak var purpleVC: PurpleViewController?
    weak var peachVC: PeachViewController?

    func selectedRow(row: Int, text: String) {
        // do something useful
    }

    func slideButtonPressed() {
        // slide purple view in or out depending on current state
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "EmbedPurple" {
            let dvc = segue.destination as! PurpleViewController
            purpleVC = dvc
            dvc.delegate = self
        }
        else if segue.identifier = "EmbedGreen" {
            let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let dvc = nav.topViewController as! GreenViewController
            greenVC = dvc
            dvc.delegate = self
        } else if segue.identifier = "EmbedPeach" {
            peachVC = segue.destination as! PeachViewController
        }
    }
}
```

In your embedded VC's, add a `delegate` pointer and call the delegate with the protocol method when it is time:

```
class GreenViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: GreenProtocol?

    @IBAction slideButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.slideButtonPressed()
    }
}

class PurpleViewController: UITableViewController {
    weak var delegate: PurpleProtocol?

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.selected(row: indexPath.row, text: modelArray[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

Comment: OK I'm new to delegates so the brain is not quite there yet..so how do I control the green from the purple then... so if I click on a button in the purple I change the VC in the green...

Comment: When you click a row in the purple, it calls `selectedRow` in the `MainViewController`.  `selectedRow` can use `greenVC` property to call methods and set properties on the `GreenViewController`.  Something like `greenVC?.someProperty = value` or `greenVC?.doSomethingUseful()`.

Comment: Ah thanks...one last thing. If I want to swap out the green for other viewcontrollers.....(that is why I put the nav in there) I'm intending the purple one to be a "menu" and the green to be content...

Comment: In that case, keep a reference to the `navCon` in your MainViewController.  You can store it in prepareForSegue. Then you can push a new VC with `navCon?.pushViewController`.

Comment: PLease see my updated response below....can't get the delegate to fire...